# Django is sending me an email about "Invalid HTTP_HOST header"

Tags: python, django

I have website that using django on **DigitialOcean**. Django is sending me an email with title `Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'url.ml'. You may need to add 'url' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.` But I don't want to add this, I added my own domains and ip address.
I have list of questions

- Why is django sending me this email?
- Bots are attacking to my site?
- If so how they do that?
- How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

As specified [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/error-reporting/#email-reports),

> When DEBUG is False, Django will email the users listed in the ADMINS
>   setting whenever your code raises an unhandled exception and results
>   in an internal server error (HTTP status code 500). This gives the
>   administrators immediate notification of any errors. The ADMINS will
>   get a description of the error, a complete Python traceback, and
>   details about the HTTP request that caused the error.

So, I guess email comes from this. If your are interested in getting more detailed trace on 500 errors, you can have a look on [Sentry](https://sentry.io), which his quite useful.

Now, regarding your error: `url.ml` I can't find any IP on this domain, but it's quite easy to had this header manually.
If you want to go deeper, you can go check your NGINX Log, aiming for IP sending those kind of requests: It might be some kind of DigitalOcean monitoring utilities, some kind of attack, you will need to get more details about that.